# HTML Components (htc)

Tags: html, html-components

Can any one suggest me a good tutorial or book  for learning  HTML Components (htc) ?

Comment: Unless you *have* to learn them I'd suggest not to waste your time doing so. Go with standards! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here are some resources on them:

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-HTMLComponents

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532146(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm not 100% sure what you meant by "learning HTML Components", I assume those are what you are after.

Answer (score 9):

HTC files are driven by the `behavior` CSS style. This is non-standard and only works in IE, so you won't be able to support users of other browsers using this method.

Because of this, virtually all the HTC behavior files I've seen have been implemented as hacks to make IE support some or other feature which other browsers already have.

For example:

- [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com)
- [WhateverHover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)

When it comes to developing HTC files, there's not actually that much to it - they're basically standard Javascript, with a small XML wrapper. If you can write Javascript in the browser, then you'll be able to write an HTC behavior file. The downside is that you won't be able to use any external Javascript, so no JQuery or other libraries.

The question is why? As I say, the only use-case that makes sense if you want to write an IE hack. Virtually everything else that you could want to use HTC for would be better implemented as straightforward Javascript, for any number of reasons.